# Given x <= y, find a sum adding to y such that all elements are <= x and decreasing and the final element is maximised

Tags: algorithms, greedy-algorithms

Given $x \leq y$, find a sum $y_1+y_2+...+y_n$ where $y_i \leq x$ and $y_{i-1} \geq y_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ and $y_n$ is maximised.

For example, given $x = 5$ and $y=17$, an optimal solution would be $17=5+4+4+4$

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercise-style tasks for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you can restrict yourself to solutions such that $y_1 - y_n \le 1$ (otherwise you can iteratively move one unit from a term with value $y_1$ to a term with value $y_n$).

Suppose now that you choose to break the sum into $n$ terms (which might not be feasible).
Then the only such solution uses $y \bmod n$ terms of value $\lceil \frac{y}{n} \rceil$ and the remaining terms (at least one) of value $\lfloor \frac{y}{n} \rfloor$.

Then the problem boils down to maximizing $\lfloor \frac{y}{n} \rfloor$, and hence minimizing $n$, with the constraint $\lceil \frac{y}{n} \rceil \le x$.
Therefore we can pick $n = \lceil \frac{y}{x} \rceil$.